# How to limit flatMap concurrency in Combine still having all source events processed?

Tags: swift, combine

If I specify the `maxPublishers` parameter then source events after first maxPublishers events won't be flat mapped. While I want to limit only concurrency. That is to continue processing next events after some of the first maxPublishers flat map publishers have completed.

```
Publishers.Merge(
    addImageRequestSubject
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(3)) { self.compressImage($0) }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(3)) { self.addImage($0) },
    addVideoRequestSubject
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(3)) { self.addVideo(url: $0) }
).sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: {})
.store(in: &cancelBag)
```

I've also tried to limit concurrency with help of OperationQueue. But `maxConcurrentOperationCount` seems doesn't have an effect.

```
Publishers.Merge(
    addImageRequestSubject
        .receive(on: imageCompressionQueue)
        .flatMap { self.compressImage($0) }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .receive(on: mediaAddingQueue)
        .flatMap { self.addImage($0) },
    addVideoRequestSubject
        .receive(on: mediaAddingQueue)
        .flatMap { self.addVideo(url: $0) }
).sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: {})
.store(in: &cancelBag)

private lazy var imageCompressionQueue: OperationQueue = {
    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3

    return queue
}()

private lazy var mediaAddingQueue: OperationQueue = {
    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3

    return queue
}()
```

Flat map publishers look this way:

```
func compressImage(_ image: UIImage) -> Future<Data?, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let result = image.compressTo(15)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
            promise(Result.success(result))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt thank you for your response. I've tried to defer my futures, but still get only 3 images being processed. Where do you mean I switch threads in not appropriate way and should use receiveOn?

Comment: @matt as regards maxPublishers, those source events are ignored that are sent while a flatMap operator is loaded with the maximum number of publishers specified. After flatMap operations have completed, I can send new source events and they will be processed successfully. This is what I can observe. But I need all the source events to be processed honouring the demand for flatMap operators.

Comment: Ok maybe you need to add a Buffer?

Comment: @matt you are right, buffer is what I missed! Do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have stumbled very beautifully right into the use case for the `.buffer` operator. Its purpose is to compensate for `.flatMap` backpressure by accumulating values that would otherwise be dropped.

I will illustrate by a completely artificial example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let sub = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var timer : Timer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sub
            .flatMap(maxPublishers:.max(3)) { i in
                return Just(i)
                    .delay(for: 3, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .sink { print($0) }
            .store(in: &storage)
        
        var count = 0
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { 
            _ in
            count += 1
            self.sub.send(count)
        }
    }
}
```

So, our publisher is emitting an incremented integer every second, but our `flatMap` has `.max(3)` and takes 3 seconds to republish a value. The result is that we start to miss values:

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
9
10
11
...
```

The solution is to put a buffer in front of the `flatMap`. It needs to be large enough to hold any missed values long enough for them to be requested:

```
        sub
            .buffer(size: 20, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropOldest)
            .flatMap(maxPublishers:.max(3)) { i in
```

The result is that all the numeric values do in fact arrive at the `sink`. Of course in real life we *could* still lose values if the buffer is not large enough to compensate for disparity between the rate of value emission from the publisher and the rate of value emission from the backpressuring `flatMap`.