# How to limit concurrent live URLSessions with Combine?

Tags: swift, combine, urlsession

I have a lot (~200) urls for images, and I need to download each one, then process (resize) it, then update the cache. The thing is - I only want to have at max 3 requests at once, and since the images are heavy, I also don't want a lot of responses "hanging" waiting to be processed (and taking memory...).

TLDR I want to call the next (4th) network request only after the `receiveValue` in the `sink` is called on one of the first 3 requests... (ie after the network response & processing are both done...).

Will this flow work, and will it hold on to the waiting urls and not drop them on the floor?

Also do I need that `buffer()` call? I use it after seeing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67011837/2242359

```swift
wayTooManyURLsToHandleAtOnce // this is a `[URL]`
    .publisher
    .buffer(size: .max, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropNewest) // NEEDED?
    .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(3)) { url in
       URLSession.shared
           .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
           .map { (data: Data, _) -> Picture in
               Picture(from: data)
           }
    }
    .tryCompactMap {
        resizeImage(picture: $0) // takes a while and might fail
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { completion
        // handling completion... 
    } receiveValue: { resizedImage
        self.cache.append(resizedImage)
    }
    .store(...)
```

Comment: If you are in any doubt as to whether your code works or whether the buffer is needed, why don't you write a test that exercises your strategy, and find out? Just substitute your own publisher for the URLSession publisher so that no networking is involved and you control the timing. There is no need to guess!

Comment: Yeap I did some testing and it seemed to be working as expected, but given my lack of experience with the APIs I was still scared that it "works by chance", and also I wasn't sure I I was doing it "the right way" or if there is a better tool for the job

Comment: It looks fine to me, except I'm a little worried about where you're doing `resizeImage`. But that wasn't your question. — Note that when I say "test" I am saying to test without networking.

Comment: I did get similar feedback offline about this (: basically the feedback was that the resize should be part of the publisher chain inside the flatMap, including the cache appending done in the sink, and the sink should only notify the UI. Was that your thinking?

Comment: Yes it was. You shouldn't do something that "takes time and might error" in the direct chain if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subject. This not an optimal solution but it looks working and maybe will trigger other ideas

```
var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

var urls: [String] = (0...6).map { _ in "http://httpbin.org/delay/" + String((0...2).randomElement()!) }

var subject: PassthroughSubject<[String], Never> = .init()

let maxConcurrentRequests = 3

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    print(urls)
    
    cancellable = subject
        .flatMap({ urls -> AnyPublisher<[URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output], URLError> in
            let requests = urls.map { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL.init(string: $0)!) }
            return Publishers.MergeMany(requests)
                .collect().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        })
        .print()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            print(completion)
        }, receiveValue: { value in
            print(value)
            if self.urls.count <= self.maxConcurrentRequests {
                self.urls.removeAll()
                self.subject.send(completion: .finished)
            } else {
                self.urls.removeLast(self.maxConcurrentRequests)
                self.subject.send(self.urls.suffix(self.maxConcurrentRequests))
            }
        })
    
    subject.send(urls.suffix(maxConcurrentRequests))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't calling `self.subject.send(completion: .finished)` on the sink end my subscription forever? (ie ignoring future values emitted)

Comment: @AvielGross Yes, it does. I understood that your collection of urls created once per view controller present / dismiss. If its not true then do not send ".finished" but you have a trigger like didSet  on urls array or another to relaunch with subject.send after emptying the array and refilling it.